# Selenium Firefox randomly freezes under Debian

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, debian

I'm running a selenium test using Firefox-17, and it will randomly "freeze" - the window is visible but completely useless.  The mouse cursor that usually shows up when you hover over a link is active over the entire firefox window, but cannot actually interact/click on the page or firefox's menus.  This only happens on the Debian machine, and only with selenium.  I use Firefox-28 for daily browsing, and I've never experienced any issues like this.

The code runs fine for several minutes, but then it always randomly freezes in the middle of requesting a new page.  The process must then be force killed.

Things I've tried:

- Using firefox-28 - still freezes at random
- Running the same code on my Windows machine - this runs for hours with no problem

Hypothesis:

- I'm running the tests with python's multiprocessing. (For debugging purposes I've only been using one master queue that feeds to a single driver instance.)
- Could this freezing problem be related to the forking mechanism used by Linux for multiprocessing?
- Maybe somehow related to the http://shallowsky.com/blog/linux/firefox-freeze-and-dbus.html - although I have no problems accessing the bbc podcast referenced in that link
- I have other code that runs firefox with javascript disabled, and it hasn't had any issues on this Debian machine.  Could this be something to do with Linux's javascript engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out that this only occurs with javascript enabled in firefox.  Fortunately, chromium doesn't have this javascript problem on the same debian system.